# Cucumber: Failed to instantiate class steps.Steps

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have created a small training Cucumber project.
My project tree:
[project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhO7z.png)

**pom dependencies**:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.13.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.13.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.13.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**Feature file structure**:

```
Feature: Checkout for a customer.
  They are searching for the book, add it to cart, proceeding to checkout and pay for it.

  Scenario: Proceed to checkout, fill all the details
    Given I am a new customer and I open the "Home page"
    And I search for "Head First. Java"
    And I select the product with title "Head First. Java"
    And I click "Add to basket" button for the given needed product and close the book info page
    And I click on the basket icon on "Search Results Page"
    And I am filling the details:
      | name       | test          |
      | secondName | test          |
      | phone      | 0123356885    |
      | email      | test@test.com |
      | country    | test          |
      | city       | test          |
      | address    | 22220         |
    And I select online payment option
    And I press the "Continue to payment" button
    And I feel my card details and press pay button
      | cardNumber | 1111111111111111 |
      | mm         | 11               |
      | yy         | 11               |
      | cvv        | 111              |
```

**My Runner**:

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"C:/Users/Hedgehog/IdeaProjects/FinalProj/src/test/java/resources/BuyBook.feature"},
        glue = {"steps"}
)

public class Runner {

}
```

**Also, here are my steps. I have not included locators and imports**

```
 @Given("I am a new customer and I open the \"Home page\"")
    public void i_open_the() throws Throwable {
        driver.get("https://www.yakaboo.ua");
    }


    @And("I search for \"Head First. Java\"")
    public void i_search_for(String bookName) throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(searchFieldLocator).sendKeys(bookName);
        driver.findElement(searchButton).click();
    }


    @And("I select the product with title \"Head First. Java\"")
    public void i_select_the_product_with_title() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(searchBookByTitle).click();
    }

    @And("I click \"Add to basket\" button for the given needed product and close the book info page")
    public void i_click_button_for_the_given_needed_product_and_close_the_book_info_page() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(searchByAddToCart).click();
        driver.findElement(searchCloseButton).click();
    }

    @And("I click on the basket icon on \"Search Results Page\"")
    public void i_click_on_the_basket_icon_on() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(searchCartButton).click();
    }

    @And("I am filling the details:")
    public void i_am_filling_the_details(DataTable dataForOrderTable) throws Throwable {
        dataForOrder = dataForOrderTable.asMap(String.class, String.class);
        driver.findElement(firstNameInputLocator).sendKeys(dataForOrder.get("name"));
        driver.findElement(secondNameInputLocator).sendKeys(dataForOrder.get("secondName"));
        driver.findElement(phoneInputLocator).sendKeys(dataForOrder.get("phone"));
        driver.findElement(emailInputLocator).sendKeys(dataForOrder.get("email"));
        driver.findElement(deliveryMethodLocator).click();
        driver.findElement(countryInputLocator).sendKeys(dataForOrder.get("country"));
        driver.findElement(desiredCountryLocator).click();
        driver.findElement(cityInputLocator).sendKeys(dataForOrder.get("city"));
        driver.findElement(desiredCityLocator).click();
        driver.findElement(addressInputLocator).sendKeys(dataForOrder.get("address"));
        driver.findElement(desiredAddressLocator).click();
    }

    @And("I select online payment option")
    public void i_select_online_payment_option() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(paymentMethodLocator).click();
    }

    @And("I press the \"Continue to payment\" button")
    public void i_press_the_button(String arg0) throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(checkoutButtonLocator).click();
    }

    @Then("I feel my card details and press pay button")
    public void i_feel_my_card_details_and_press_pay_button(DataTable cardDetailsTable) throws Throwable {
        cardDetails = cardDetailsTable.asMap(String.class, String.class);
        driver.findElement(cardNumberLocator).sendKeys(cardDetails.get("cardNumber"));
        driver.findElement(dueMonthLocator).sendKeys(cardDetails.get("mm"));
        driver.findElement(dueYearLocator).sendKeys(cardDetails.get("yy"));
        driver.findElement(cvvLocator).sendKeys(cardDetails.get("cvv"));
        driver.findElement(payButtonLocator).click();
    }
```

When I try to start the runner I get the exception `Failed to instantiate class steps.Steps`

Previously I had some problems because of POM file, I solved the initial problem and now get the above error.
Not sure where to go from here.

I have created a smaller Cucumber project, just one step and it worked fine.
So, I assume, something's wrong with my steps.
Before the actual steps, I added all the locators as separate variables.

Comment: Your `glue` is wrong. It should be `"steps"`.

Comment: And with the correct glue your tests will be skipped and some steps skipped because you have `throw new PendingException()` in your steps.

Comment: Have a look at this to help you solve problems in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: For your latest problem. What is in the stack trace? And what does your step class constructor look like?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem. It appears that I have not added the path to the chromedriver
Thus adding the following code into my Steps class resolved the issue:

```
    @Before
public void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to the driver on your machine");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```